# Can I read a configuration file (*.ini) from Dask worker using the "client.upload_file" method?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm attempting to read a config file `(config.ini)` for reading logging configuration from Dask workers. I'm aware of the `client.upload_file()` method, so I zipped up my file to `config.ini.zip`. But can anyone tell me if it's possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do using that method, and if it is how to do it? Eventually, I want to be able to use the following in my Dask computation:

```
import logging

logging.config.fileCongfig(fname="config.ini", disable_existing_loggers=False)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Client.upload_file` to upload files, and then `Client.run` to run arbitrary Python code.  Perhaps a combination of those two would solve your problem?

Comment: As I asked in my question, does this work for non-Python files, like configuration files `config.ini`, and if so, how?

Comment: The upload_file method uploads any file, not just Python files.